# search current date jquery in xml elements and display in html5

Tags: jquery, xml, date, element

i want to display schedule prayer time data from jakim malaysia

amin007.github.io/phparastinggi/rangka-dawai/contoh/5/rss-ke-json/jadual_kuliah4.html

but right now i can get schedule prayer time in month August 2017
amin007.github.io/phparastinggi/rangka-dawai/contoh/5/rss-ke-json/waktu_solat_bulan_08.xml

from this file -> amin007.github.io/phparastinggi/rangka-dawai/contoh/5/rss-ke-json/jadual_kuliah5.html

i can get current date today

```
var today = GetTodayDate();
```

how i can find var today in waktu_solat_bulan_08.xml

```
<item28><Tarikh>29 Ogos</Tarikh><Hari>Selasa</Hari><Imsak>5:39</Imsak><Subuh>5:49</Subuh><Syuruk>7:05</Syuruk><Zohor>13:12</Zohor><Asar>16:24</Asar><Maghrib>19:16</Maghrib><Isyak>20:26</Isyak></item28>
```

and display all elements in item28 base of date today?

=============================================================================
Solution

1. change data waktu_solat_bulan_08.xml
2. refer [Jquery Find an XML element based on the value of one of it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063963/jquery-find-an-xml-element-based-on-the-value-of-one-of-its-children)

Comment: my question how u get the current date day?

Comment: give u some hint here, get the date, after that do some slicing and then use ajax searching and filtering from the xml , when it success append it in to your dom element.

Comment: @Fiido93, i get current date day in function function GetTodayDate() {
var tdate = new Date();
 var dd = tdate.getDate(); //yields day
 var mm = tdate.getMonth(); //yields month
 var yyyy = tdate.getFullYear(); //yields year
 var bulan = Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mac', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun',
  'Jul', 'Ogos', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dis');
 var xxx = dd + ' ' + bulan[mm] + ' ' + yyyy;

 return xxx;
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063963/jquery-find-an-xml-element-based-on-the-value-of-one-of-its-children