# jQuery and XML, find object that contains children with multiple specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

For a project I have data stored in XML like this:

```xml
<xml>
    <sprites>
        <sprite>
            <name>Tile1</name>
            <lat>1</lat>
            <lng>2</lng>
        </sprite>
        <sprite>
            <name>Tile2</name>
            <lat>3</lat>
            <lng>4</lng>
        </sprite>
    </sprites>
<xml>
```

Through jQuery I want to get a tile object that matches two child values, the lat and lng values.

[I found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064072/3461722) which was of great help, but sadly it only has an example of how to search for one matching value. Here's the code I have up to now:

```js
// xml stored in 'xml' var

var findLat = 3;
var findLng = 4;

var mapSprites = $(xml).find("sprites");

var getSprite = $(mapSprites).find("sprite").filter(
    function() {
        return $(this).find('lat').text() == findLat;
    },
    function() {
        return $(this).find('lng').text() == findLng;
    }
);
```

Sadly `getSprite` is undefined, as I'm guessing you can't use the filter function as I've tried to use it? The example I linked to has one function as filter and seems to work, but comma separating doesn't seem to work as an `AND`, which is what I need.

The goal is to be able to give the function a lat and lng value and me being able to extract the `<name>` value.

Would be thankful for a push in the right direction, I'm pretty new to XML and parsing it through jQuery.

Comment: problem is filter does not take two arguments like that....

Comment: One function to filter, `return (condition1 && condition2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter does not take multiple arguments. So combine it into one using "and".

```
var findLat = 3;
var findLng = 4;

var mapSprites = $(xml).find("sprites");
var getSprite = mapSprites.find("sprite").filter(
  function() {
    const node = $(this);
    return Number(node.find('lat').text()) === findLat &&
      Number(node.find('lng').text()) === findLng;
  }
);
```

Comment: @Taplar Yeah, I noticed that as I added the other code. I removed the unneeded $()

Comment: Thank you, fixed! Took me a bit longer because I apparently had some other errors in my code but your answer helped me find those too.